# Find bounding box for multiple locations with bb_lookup

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I am trying to find the bounding box coordinates of multiple locations. The Nominatim tool uses OpenStreetMap data to do this task using the function bb_lookup. However, I haven't been able to determine how to use this function for more than one location at a time (ie. for a dataframe of many locations)

This is the function I have tried so far:
`output <- bb_lookup("Charlotte, NC")`

I also tried to apply the function with map and lapply:

```
map(list_of_locations,bb_lookup)
lapply(list_of_locations,bb_lookup)
```

and got the error values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) results is length 9 when I test a list_of_locations with 9 locations

What I'd like to be able to do is something along the lines of:

`list_of_locations <- c("Charlotte, NC","Mercedes Benz Stadium")`

`output <- bb_lookup(list_of_locations)`

When I try something similar to this, I get an error of "unused arguments".

Comment: Use base `lapply` (or another in the `apply`) family, or `purrr::map` to apply this function along the vector of locations

Comment: I tried both but am now getting the error "Values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) results is length 9" (note: I am attempting to run a sample of 9 locations in list_of_locations)

Comment: What *exactly* did you try? It will be helpful for you to [edit] the post with the code that hasn't worked

Comment: Edited above with code.

Comment: And what package does `bb_lookup` come from?

Comment: Nominatim, the tool referenced in the question. It's not a package on its own, but referenced by library(nominatim). Not available to download using "install.packages(nominatim)", so I didn't want to call it a package.

Comment: Okay got it. It is a package, just not on CRAN: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim

Comment: Yep, exactly! Wasn't sure how to explain that properly.

Comment: Using `nominatim` v0.2.2.9000 and a fresh R session, I get a list of bounding boxes and other info using either of the two lines of code you have (`lapply` and `purrr::map`). So I'm not sure what's going wrong

Comment: Now it's miraculously working?! Didn't even refresh R... Thank you for your help! Both lapply and map worked.